# Normal AM-GM inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Minimum value of $\frac{x^2}{x-9}$

I was asked to use the AM-GM inequality to solve this, I was thinking that I should express it into 2 fractions, and so I did, I tried to express $x^2$ as 
$\frac{(x-9)^2 +18x -81 }{x-9}$, though I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: On which interval do you want to minimise this?

Comment: the Minimum is $$-\infty$$

Comment: Please, you should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts by now.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Set $x-9=h$
$$\dfrac{x^2}{x-9}=\dfrac{(h+9)^2}h=h+\dfrac{9^2}h+18$$

If $h>0\iff x-9>0$  $$\dfrac{h+\dfrac{9^2}h}2\ge\sqrt{h\cdot\dfrac{9^2}h}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll try
$$\frac{x^2}{x-9}=\frac{x^2-81+81}{x-9} =x+9+\frac{81}{x-9}=x-9+\frac{81}{x-9}+18$$
$$x-9+\frac{81}{x-9}+18 \ge 2\sqrt{(x-9)\left(\frac{81}{x-9}\right)}+18=2\cdot9+18=36$$